# Unix Shell scripting to change background colour of putty

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, putty

Is there any way to change background colour of putty through shell scripting?
For eg: Suppose I login to server X from putty. and now I want to write a script in server X so that when I do ssh to server Y, the background colour of putty should change to red and when I do ssh to server Z from X, the background colour should be green.
Could anyone please tell whether Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This works for me in linux, don't know about putty... `setterm -term linux -back blue -fore white -clear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use escape code color (they are are terminal dependant so consult your own device info for specific value avalaible)

I use on my AIX (variable name could be shorter)

```
#-- move
__Term_Disp_Esc_LF="\n"
__Term_Disp_Esc_CR="\r"
__Term_Disp_Esc_INVT="\033[7m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_NORM="\033[0m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_BOLD="\033[1m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_BLINK="\033[5m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_UNDR="\033[2m\033[4m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_EOL="\033[0K"
__Term_Disp_Esc_EOD="\033[0J"
__Term_Disp_Esc_UNDR="\033[4m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_EOL="\033[0K"
__Term_Disp_Esc_EOD="\033[0J"
__Term_Disp_Esc_SOD="\033[1;1f"
__Term_Disp_Esc_CUR_UP="\033[1A"
__Term_Disp_Esc_CUR_DOWN="\033[1B"
__Term_Disp_Esc_CUR_LEFT="\033[1D"
__Term_Disp_Esc_CUR_RIGHT="\033[1C"

#-- ANSI code
__Term_Disp_Esc_SCR_HOME="\033[0;0H" #-- Home of the display

#-- Color
__Term_Disp_Esc_BLACK_F="\033[30m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_BLACK_B="\033[40m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_RED_F="\033[31m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_RED_B="\033[41m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_GREEN_F="\033[32m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_GREEN_B="\033[42m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_YELLOW_F="\033[33m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_YELLOW_B="\033[43m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_BLUE_F="\033[34m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_BLUE_B="\033[44m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_MAGENTA_F="\033[35m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_MAGENTA_B="\033[45m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_CYAN_F="\033[36m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_CYAN_B="\033[46m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_WHITE_F="\033[37m"
__Term_Disp_Esc_WHITE_B="\033[47m"

# Example: bold
#echo "${__Term_Disp_Esc_BOLD}Bold test ${__Term_Disp_Esc_NORM}"
```